# Edit with IDLE disappeared for .py files

Tags: python, windows, python-idle

I used to have the `Edit with IDLE` option when I right-clicked on `.py` files but I uninstalled/reinstalled multiple times to get some stuff working and now it's gone. I checked the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` for value under `Python.File` and `Python.NoConFile` and it is `"C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" -e "%1"` so I am not sure why it isn't working. It works for `.pyw` files though. Can someone help me get this working again? I've also tried repairing my python installation to no avail and following [Python IDLE disappeared from the right click context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/343519/python-idle-disappeared-from-the-right-click-context-menu).

Comment: I don't know much about this error, but you should take a look in http://superuser.com/questions/280636/trying-to-edit-a-python-file-but-the-edit-with-idle-has-disappeared-when-i-rig maybe you'll find something useful

Comment: @Pardoido well that worked but it isn't quite what I had in mind. It opens IDLE with the `Edit` option now which is fine but I would ultimately like the `Edit with IDLE` option back.

Comment: I had the same problem and i solved it by uninstall python and removing from registry. After that i installed the python and everything came back to normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens because a .py file has been opened in a text editor and accidentally set the default "open with" option to something other than python.

Try:

- right click on a .py file
- open with...
- choose default program...
- tick *always use the selected program to open this kind of file*
- choose python.exe

This runs the script in a terminal, but also sets the filetype back to python.

Now check the right click menu again.

...

And for those people thinking **durr it's not that simple**, just try it first - It might prevent you from hacking about in the registry for no reason!

Comment: Haha well that did it but I think it was a combination of things because I did that multiple times before. That was already the default program but I clicked it again and now everything is working fine.

Comment: @Quirk This really does answer the question, because 8 times out of 10 with this issue, the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command still exists with the correct value "C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" -e "%1", but windows just doesn't look there. Windows will only look under the Python.File key if the default program is set to python.exe

Comment: I think part of it was that there was no `.py` key in the registry. I'm assuming all previous attempts at setting `python.exe` as the default failed because of this.

Comment: what is the full path of the .py key you had to create? the reason I ask is because lots of people get directed to create the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.py but this is a red herring and can be deleted again

Comment: That is what I added and it made it so when I clicked edit then it would open in IDLE but it still didn't have the option to `Edit with IDLE`

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing can be Windows version and Python version specific, and maddening to fix.  There are extensions, abstract file types, and executables.  For me, with Windows 10 and 3.5.1, `assoc` in Command Prompt returns a list of .xyz associations that includes

```
.py=Python.File
.pyc=Python.CompiledFile
.pyo=Python.CompiledFile
.pyw=Python.NoConFile
.pyz=Python.ArchiveFile
.pyzw=Python.NoConArchiveFile
```

`assoc .py=Python.File` will set an association.  Once these are set correctly, there is still the issue of mapping abstract file types to executable commands.  Mark Ch's answer address this part.

Comment: `assoc` and `ftype` modify the system's `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` association and ProgId. User preferences override this in Explorer's `FileExts` key. This could select the system's ProgId, or maybe one defined in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`, or an application from `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications`. The last one is a common problem for Python since it gets created automatically when users "look for another app on this PC" and navigate to the installation directory to select "python.exe". The "open" command this creates has no `%*` entry, so command-line arguments are ignored.

Comment: If Steve Dower moved the `editwithidle` key from `Python.File\Shell` to `SystemFileAssociations\.py\Shell`, it would still be available on the right-click menu when the user associates a different `ProgId`. The [`SystemFileAssociations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121#reg_verbs) key sets up low-priority defaults.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest that i've got a better way to solve this problem. 
right click at the .py file, open with, choose another app, more apps and make sure to check the check box that says 'always use this app to open .py files', then look for another app on this pc, a window explorer will open. then choose this file C:\Python34\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat 
One more thing, the icon for python files(python logo disappears) which i don't like. but any way the python file will be open in python IDLE editor, with just one click(i set my mouse to one click from double click).

Thank you for reading my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have been using python 3.6, and ran into this issue after installing (and later removing) python 2.7
(Thankfully i had another machine with a clean install)

**To restore "Edit with IDLE" / file icons / open option:**

Make a .reg file with the following, right-click it, and choose 'merge':

( NOTE: "C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" should be correct, but double check that the .exe is there first)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py]
@="Python.File"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File]
@="Python File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\py.exe\",1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\editwithidle]
"MUIVerb"="&Edit with IDLE"
"Subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\editwithidle\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\py.exe\" \"%L\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyw]
@="Python.NoConFile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile]
@="Python File (no console)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\py.exe\",1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell\editwithidle]
"MUIVerb"="&Edit with IDLE"
"Subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell\editwithidle\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\pyw.exe\" \"%L\" %*"
```

**Adding/Fixing versions to the menu:**

Here is an example .reg for IDLE 3.6 32 bit, where the █'s are the path to the install (use double \'s)

for other versions change **"Edit with IDLE 3.6 (32-bit)"** and **edit36-32** to match your version

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\editwithidle\shell\edit36-32]
"MUIVerb"="Edit with IDLE 3.6 (32-bit)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\editwithidle\shell\edit36-32\command]
@="\"███████████████\\pythonw.exe\" -m idlelib \"%L\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell\editwithidle\shell\edit36-32]
"MUIVerb"="Edit with IDLE 3.6 (32-bit)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell\editwithidle\shell\edit36-32\command]
@="\"███████████████\\pythonw.exe\" -m idlelib \"%L\" %*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also downloaded python 3-4 times, but I realised that you must choose to open .py files with python launcher, the icon with the spaceship.

1. So, right click on a .py file
2. Open with ...
3. Choose another program
4. Make sure the "always use the selected program for .py files" is ticked
5. Choose the python program with the spaceship.

This solved my problem, I hope it will also solve yours.